# Is it possible to run multiple Iperf clients simultaneously?

Tags: networking, server, iperf

Is it possible to run iperf clients simultaneously such that if I have 10 servers bound to some machine B, and I have 10 clients on machine A, and all the servers have distinct IP addresses, could I run all of these clients at the same time via threading? Or is there pre-existing Linux support for this type of behavior (similar to like how iperf has -D daemon mode for server)? Thanks for all the help, I tried finding resources on this online but was unable to find something similar.

Answer (score 1):

this could be a solution to this problem:
https://sandilands.info/sgordon/multiple-iperf-instances

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.